# Django CBV queryset issue

Tags: python, django

this is my model

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
text = models.TextField()
create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.author} --> {self.title}'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def unpublish(self):
    self.published_date = None
    self.save()
```

and i registered it on Django admin. i have created two post on Django admin, the new post when i  publish it and hit now and refresh the page, it won't show this post:

this is admin code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment

@admin.register(Post, Comment)
class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

this is the view:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
queryset = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
print('query0: ', queryset)

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    print('query1: ', queryset)
    print('query2:', self.queryset)
    print('query3: ', Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()))
    return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

[image]

As you can see result of query1, query2 is different with query3.

I think this is a bug, if it's not please light me up.

Comment: Can you add the code that prints the three queries and the code where you call the publish method?

Comment: Please share the view where you print the queries. Likely you cached the query somewhere, hence it will not refresh.

Comment: Please add your admin panel codes to your question.

Comment: sorry i added view class

Comment: i don't user publish method yet

Comment: The class attribute queryset defined in PostListView is created once when your app starts, it will always filter using the value of `timezone.now()` at the time when your app started. To test this, try restarting your app after publishing and see if the result changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's been answered by
[Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) in a comment:

> The class attribute queryset defined in PostListView is created once when your app starts, it will always filter using the value of `timezone.now()` at the time when your app started. To test this, try restarting your app after publishing and see if the result changes